# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{

Tags: android, android-activity, xmlhttprequest, nullpointerexception, components

I have the following mistake:

```
12-05 20:35:31.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helplawyer/com.example.helplawyer.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

in xml manifest I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

this is my main class

```
package com.example.helplawyer;


public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.consultant.ru/rss/hotdocs.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainxml);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
        map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.cost, R.id.link });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

}

XMLParser

```
package com.example.helplawyer;

public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

}

I read on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559381/e-androidruntime3306-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-com) that I need to use `new Thread(new Runnable() {`
but I don't understand how to rewrite my code that my app works good.
Please, help me with my problem!
Thank you

Comment: Its not clear, where you get Exception? please add info about that. Further, from Exception I don't see any reference to code you posted.

Comment: where you are calling getXmlFromUrl method post relevant code then we will try help u

Answer (score 1):

From the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

> **The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.**
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.
>
> Also see StrictMode.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) for examples of running this operation in the background (Find "*How to Avoid ANRs*")

Answer (score 0):

You are running `Network Request` on main `UI thread`.

`Android >=3.0` does not allow to run `Network Request` on main `UI thread`. You need to use

`AsyncTask` to do network operation.

Comment: Am I right, that AsyncTask needs because my "parser" works with "long and heavy task" and that's why Android doesn't start my app?

Comment: @user1873342 you are performing network operation on main ui thread which is not possible android=>3.0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access network from your main thread.
you need to use AsyncTask . Check my answer at
[Android Connecting with PHP and MySql Force Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380941/android-connecting-with-php-and-mysql-force-close/13381073#13381073)

Note the `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`, here first `String` is the parameter to `doInBackground` , `Void` is parameter to `onProgressUpdate()`, we are not implementing this method, second `String` is parameter to `onPostExecute()`

Now, from `MainActivity` when you call `new InnerClass().execute(urltoxml);` Android will automatically call `doInBackground()` and will pass `urltoxml` as the argument`

Do all your network stuff inside `doInbackground`, when finished, doInBackground will return a result `string` and android will pass that as the parameter to `onPostExecute()`.
Use that string however you want from onPostExecute

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        new InnerClass().execute(urltoxml);
    }

    });
}

public class InnerClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String returnVal;
        //process your xml here
        //store the result in returnVal;
        return returnVal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do something with the data
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you Robin.I've just tried. I have a question: can you show me how to Call new MyInnerClass().execute(); from my main Activity. (example code).

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I updated my code above. I have a parser xml that consists from public class XMLParser and public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity

As I know, I need to insert into protected String doInBackground a part of public String getXmlFromUrl from XMLParser class.

But I don't understand what is my next step and how it connects with  AndroidXMLParsingActivity class

Comment: I don't see any updated code above. You have copied XMLParser class twice in your question

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. I've deleted a copy of code.
Can you explain me how can I insert into "doInBackground" and "onPostExecute" my code from public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity and public class XMLParser
Thank you very much!

Comment: I uses an ArrayList (menuItems) and it's confused me when I try to insert into "doInBackground"